# EMF : Keeping up with different version of ecore model

Tags: eclipse, emf, pde

When we made initial release of our model we had the following model
1. Person:String:Name,String :Address
2. Version : 1.0

so export /import was easy using EMF's persistent APIs(Storing them as xmls).

Now we have changed the model to
1. Person :String:Name,Address
2. Address: String:House Number, String:Stree Name, String:City
3. Version : 2.0

The same thing explained below

[image]

Now how to support older xml files(which are exported using old model) in the new Model.

Is there any support in EMF to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some tools/frameworks to help with model migration. [Edapt](https://www.eclipse.org/edapt/) is probably the most well-known (and an official Eclipse project). Basically, it includes tooling and runtime support that tracks the history of your metamodels and can migrate instances at runtime. There was a [talk about it](https://www.eclipsecon.org/na2016/session/model-migration-edapt) at EclipseCon earlier this year.

I've also heard of another project, [EMF Migrate](http://www.emfmigrate.org/), but I don't know much about it.

Comment: After spending some time on Edapt looks like the solution which I was looking for. thanks